# Create Highchart graph from specific CSV file

Tags: date, csv, import, highcharts, temperature

I'm new to using php/jscript/etc. At the moment I'm working at meteo station, using Arduino to save data in CSV file. It looks like:

> 1,25.65
>
> 2,25.44
>
> 3,24.81
>
> 4,25.55
>
> 6,24.56

I've read how-to use CSV file in Highchart where header line containes categories the rest of the lines contain data with their name in the first position.

But I'd like to have categories named in script (X-time, Y-temperature). And first position is time and rest is data.

I'm trying scripts from this site, but it's all blank after I put them into my htm :(

Comment: Take look at http://docs.highcharts.com/#preprocesssing-data-from-a-file and I'd like to know if which names should have categories? if you have no these titles in csv ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
var series = {
    data: []
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    var options = {
        chart: { renderTo: 'container', defaultSeriesType: 'line' },
        title: { text: 'Chart Example' },
        xAxis: { title: { text: 'Time' }, categories: []    },
        yAxis: { title: { text: 'Temperature'    } },
        series: []
    };
    $.get('data.csv', function(data) {
        var lines = data.split('\n');
        $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
            var items = line.split(',');

            $.each (items, function(itemNo, item) {
                if (itemNo == 0) {
                    options.xAxis.categories.push(item);
                }
                else {
                    series.data.push(parseFloat(item));
                }
            });                    
        });
        options.series.push(series);
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });
});
```

Where 'container' is a div, and `data.csv` is the file containing your data (in the same directory as your HTML file)